# Cannot assign to non-existent property

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to make a very simple program to learn how to define custom QML types for reuse. I'm not sure why I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot assign to non-existent property "color"

I have searched for an answer and have not found anything that solves it.

Below is the code. Qt underlines `color` and `radius` in red, meaning that it is being flagged as an "invalid property name."

```
//Button.qml
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle {
width: 100; height: 100
color: "red"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: console.log("button clicked!")
    }
}

//main.qml 
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Open")
                onTriggered: console.log("Open action triggered");
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    Column {
        Button {width: 50; height: 50}
        Button { x: 50; width: 100; height: 50; color: "blue" }
        Button { width: 50; height: 50; radius: 8}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Qt Quick Controls has a `Button` type, and so do you. Apparently the `Button` from the Qt Quick Controls import (which has no `radius` or `color` property) gets chosen over your local file. You have a few options:

1. Rename your `Button` type to something else.
2. Import Qt Quick Controls into a namespace.
3. Import your type into a namespace.

Here's how you'd do option #2:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2 as Controls

Controls.ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: Controls.MenuBar {
        Controls.Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            Controls.MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Open")
                onTriggered: console.log("Open action triggered")
            }
            Controls.MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit()
            }
        }
    }

    Column {
        Button {
            width: 50
            height: 50
        }
        Button {
            x: 50
            width: 100
            height: 50
            color: "blue"
        }
        Button {
            width: 50
            height: 50
            radius: 8
        }
    }
}
```